# What is the Japanese (onomatopoeic) sound that corduroy pants make?

Tags: words, onomatopoeia, sound-symbolism

Would this be the correct way to ask in Japanese?

```
"コージュロイズボンは何の音をするのですか"
```

Comment: Now I want to know… what sound *do* they make‽

Answer (score 2):

> "コージュロイズボンは何の音をするのですか"

I would say...

コーデュロイパンツは**どんな**音**が**｛しますか / するんですか / するのですか｝？

Comment: （でも...コーデュロイパンツって音する？）

Comment: 微妙にするんちゃう、一応？文字に起こすとなるとムズイけど。

Comment: @Chocolate I'm sure I'm just being stupid but why is it が and not を?

Comment: @user3856370 音がする is the idiom for saying "to make a sound".  If you're thinking コージュロイズ is the subject, that would sound very odd in Japanese, as if the corduroys had a life of their own.